# Launch docker in flexible way with changeable program arguments

Tags: java, bash, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose v3. The most interesting configuration part is:

```
entrypoint:
  - java
  - -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=docker-test -jar /app.jar
```

please pay your attention on `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=docker-test -jar /app.jar` - the active profile is `docker-test`. This configuration works for me. Trying to improve one, moving profile value to separate variable:

```
environment:
 - profiles=docker-test
```

and updating `java` parameters with improvement:

```
  - -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=$profiles -jar /app.jar
```

program fails. Checking logs:

```
INFO 1 --- [           main] c.s.n.d.m.d.DiscoveryServiceApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

it means docker improvement is not visible on java level, it seems variable `$profiles` was not replaced with value of its. Comparing  java level with previous example - value is changed but expectation is it must be the same.

Is any ideas how to fix it?

### P.S.

In case I'm doing the similar thing on `Dockerfile` level - it works:

```
ENV profiles=docker-test
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=$profiles -jar /app.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use [an `.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) for this. Docker Compose cannot replace the variables in `environment:` in other parts of your configuration file (`entrypoint:` in this case). You can check that when you run `docker-compose config` in your project folder and you will see that `profiles` is empty.

Create a file called `.env` in the same directory where your `docker-compose.yml` lives. The content should be:

```
profiles=docker-test
```

Then you should be good to go.

**Minimal example:**

- docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  foo:
    image: alpine
    entrypoint:
      - echo
      - "$bar"
```

- .env

```
bar="i was correctly read"
```

Results in:

```
nico@tuxedo:~/StackOverflow$ docker-compose config
services:
  foo:
    entrypoint:
    - echo
    - '"i was correctly read"'
    image: alpine
version: '3.7'
```

```
nico@tuxedo:~/StackOverflow$ docker-compose up
Starting stackoverflow_foo_1 ... done
Attaching to stackoverflow_foo_1
foo_1  | "i was correctly read"
stackoverflow_foo_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: Can you please describe life cycle maybe in your answer ( ...some special conditions, behavior of life cycle depending on it and so on.)? I was informed about `.env` before, but this approach unfortunately doesn't work for described case.

Comment: Why doesn't it work in your case? I will add a minimal example to my answer. For your other questions, please concern the Docker documentation that I have already linked in the answer. There you will find more thorough answers than I could provide here.

Comment: It seem i failed with your recommendation. I've missed `"`